# Can I, and how do I, remove older versions of the kernel in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space

I installed Ubuntu 9.10 on a computer with 4 GB available space (I can't delete stuff from the Windows partition yet).  After two automatic `Update Manager` updates, my disk space is almost all gone.  In `grub` I can see the following list of OS choices:

```
Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-20-generic
Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-20-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-19-generic
Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-19-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-14-generic
Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-14-generic (recovery mode)
Windows
```

I'm confident -20 is running well, so is it possible to remove the -14 and -19 versions?  Note that I'm asking is it possible to remove those kernel versions from the disk, not just from `grub`.  Will this free up much disk space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run `uname -a` to verify you are running the right kernel

```
sudo apt-get remove '.*2.6.31-14.*'
sudo apt-get remove '.*2.6.31-19.*'
```

should do the trick... it will remove the kernel and any other related packages for that version.  Give it a look over to make sure that only kernel related stuff matches before you enter 'y'.. I don't know of any packages that would have a version of 2.6.31-14 that are not kernel related, but it doesn't hurt to check.

I'd leave the previous kernel for a while until you are sure that the latest one is stable.

also,

running `apt-get clean` will remove all of the old .debs you have on your system.

you can install debian-goodies and run dpigs to see what packages are the biggest.

```
justin@eee:~$ dpigs
111836 openoffice.org-core
88128 linux-image-2.6.31-19-generic
71556 linux-headers-2.6.31-19
48516 google-chrome-unstable
44848 openoffice.org-common
44044 wireshark-common
37776 libgl1-mesa-dri
33976 gimp-data
33012 smbclient
24672 vim-runtime
```

There is also the "Disk Usage Analyzer" program in Accessories that you can use to see what is taking up space, or run

```
du -acx / | sort -n
```

You can also try system -> administration -> computer janitor, but I never use it and have heard mixed things about it.

Comment: @justin - Wonderful, thanks.  The `apt-get remove` lines were exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Use `yum list` to get the exact package names, then `yum erase` to remove them.

Comment: the question was about ubuntu.