# Grub finds a lot of kernel images

Tags: linux, grub

I have a PC with Ubuntu and Kali. In th output of "update-grub2" or in the GRUB menu, I see many images. Are they useful? If they aren't, how can I delete them?

```
$ sudo update-grub2
[sudo] password for user: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Attenzione: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-62-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-62-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-60-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-60-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-59-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-59-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-57-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-57-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-55-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-55-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-53-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-52-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-52-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-51-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-51-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-50-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-50-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-48-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-48-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-46-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-46-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-45-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-45-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-43-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-41-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-41-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-40-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-40-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-37-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-37-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-36-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-36-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-34-generic
Trovata immagine linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
Trovata immagine initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Trovato Kali GNU/Linux 1.1.0 (1.1.0) su /dev/sda6
fatto
```

"Attenzione" means "Warning", "Trovata immagine linux" means "found linux image" and "fatto" means "done".

Comment: duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/116749/can-i-and-how-do-i-remove-older-versions-of-the-kernel-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Are they useful?**

I suspect they are old versions of the Linux kernel that have been left there after the system' auto-update feature has installed new versions as they become available.

They are only useful if the new version doesn't work and you want to revert the change. In other words, no.

> **If they aren't, how can I delete them?**

`sudo rm path/filename` ought to work. There's probably a kinder method involving the package manager for your distro (I'm not familiar with Kali). You should be able to ask the package manager to list installed packages and may be able to  delete packages relating to these old Kernels.

Unless they are huge I'd not bother. YMMV.

Comment: On Ubuntu, you can use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove old packages. Ubuntu likes to keep the last few kernels installed, so your system remains boot-able in case of any issues with the latest, so this method will not remove all of the extra ones.